# Пересчет валют PHP

Tags: php

Как сделать пересчет валют, чтоб выводилась та валюта которая не равняется 0
Другими словами, должно умножаться то, что вводится в БД, если ввел цену в долларе и курс доллара, а евро не ввел, то умножаться должен только долларовая функция.
Сразу извиняюсь за примитивное объяснение, но я это понимаю так.

```
$europrice = $row{"eurorate"} * $row{"europrice"};
$dollarprice = $row{"dollarrate"} * $row{"dollarprice"};
$finishprice = $dollarprice or $europrice;
echo '
$finishprice ???
';
```

Comment: вместо `or` написать плюс `$dollarprice + $europrice;`, вам ведь сумма нужна в переменной $finishprice? если да, то вот [пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd60739d41c9c49e8c412a6224e64a069ba34fbc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($row["europrice"] != null)
{
 $price = $row["eurorate"] * $row["europrice"]; // Если вписана цена в евро
}
if($row["dollarprice"] != null)
{
 $price = $row["dollarrate"] * $row["dollarprice"]; // Если вписана цена в долларах
}


echo "Цена: ".$price;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Ваше решение помогло